# jQuery UI Slider - Custom Slide Button that changes based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a slider that is working as needed, but I am missing one step. I need the custom slider button to change based on what step it is on. I have tried multiple things with no luck. Any thoughts?

[Here is a link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4abfep8/45/)

```
 <div id="slider-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="slide first">Slide 1</li>
    <li class="slide second">Slide 2</li>
    <li class="slide third">Slide 3</li>
  </ul>
</div> 
<div id="slider-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
    <li>Nav 3</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to update the `background` according to the slides position. Updating the code in your fiddle, you would have something like this:

```
$("#slider").slider({
  value: 1,
  min: 1,
  max: 3,
  step: 1,
  change: function(event, ui) {
    $('.slide').fadeOut('500');
    switch(ui.value) {
      case 1:
        $('.slide.first').delay('400').fadeIn('500');
        $('.ui-slider-handle').css('background', "url('/img/logo.png') no-repeat");
        break;
      case 2:
        $('.slide.second').delay('400').fadeIn('500');
        $('.ui-slider-handle').css('background', "url('https://placehold.it/40x40') no-repeat");
        break;
      case 3:
        $('.slide.third').delay('400').fadeIn('500');
        $('.ui-slider-handle').css('background', "url('https://placehold.it/40x40/ff0000/000000') no-repeat");
        break;
    }    
  }
});
```

I'm using placeholder images, which you can update at your discretion.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/a4abfep8/51/)**